# Improving Login-Security through denial of Copy & Paste?

Tags: security, passwords, clipboard

we have a common login form for an webapplication, nothing fancy, something like

`...<input type="text" value="Username" /><input type="password" value="" />...`

My co-worker argues that denying the user to copy & paste within the login form would improve the application security.
I think otherwise because the password input is already protected by the browser itself (You cannot copy the password from the input element).

However, we added the following JScripts to the input elements:

```
... onpaste="return false;" oncopy="return false;" ondrag="return false;" ondrop="return false;" ...
```

A tester criticised that it is still possible to "drag" copy with the CRT key, of course it will only copy the * characters and not the password, but it still allowes to copy values from the form, and so the test case was returned as failed.

So much for the background.

**My Question:**

Is there any security improvement at all from denying any kind of copy & paste within the login form that is worth the extra effort?

Thanks you
Simon

Comment: Your cow-orker has too much time on his hands. Interfaces that change the default behaviour of standard controls are annoying, confusing and hurt efficiency. I have had to suffer web forms that don't allow me to copy-paste. It's annoying and doesn't add anything. Don't do it.

Comment: I'm using 20-30 character long passwords, along with password managers. I would never use web site or application that doesn't allow copy-paste :)

Comment: I use a password safe with 40+ character random passwords in some cases.  There is no way in hell I'm going to log into any site that restricts pasting to a password field.  It's the stupidest, most naive suggestion I've ever heard.  Don't do it.  Guru.com does it and it's pissing me off, and I'm just going to add a filter to disable this feature anyway, since it's easily overridable on the client-side.  Think about how dumb that is as a security feature... something that can be easily overridden on the client side.  Forcing a user to type a password just makes key loggers happier, too.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No. Why stop the user from copy-pasting their own password?

Whenever you're looking at a security protection like this, it's important to ask yourself: Exactly what kind of attacks are am I trying to protect against? In this case, even if you prevent copy-paste, the user can just retype it if they really want to, after all. And if you're worried about Evil Spyware, that stuff can just install a browser extension and look at the password in the DOM directly, or install a keylogger and capture it as it's being typed.

Indeed, this can even reduce security. Consider if the user's using a password management program that can either put the password into the clipboard, or display it for retyping. If you prevent paste, that means the user must display the password on screen for any shoulder surfers to see.

Comment: +1.  Especially for saying that you need to evaluate exactly what it is you hope to protect against before applying a silly restriction on the user.

Comment: I just had this problem with logging into the apple developer centre. They have "onpaste='return false;'" set within the password field for logging in. As I use KeepassX to manage my passwords and definetely don't have headspace to remember my apple id and password this is a PITA. The *fastest* way around this for me was to copy the password to the clipboard from KeepassX, open the webpage in developer mode in chrome, change the callback to "return true;" then paste my password in and login. Total Fail for apple on usability here.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing there are GreaseMonkey scripts which solve the Apple dev centre login PITA: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/123395

Comment: What a joke.  Just open a web console and run this to reenable pasting on a page:  `javascript:(function(){var H=["paste"], Z=[], s="", j; function R(N,a){ while (N[a]) { Z[a]=Z[a]?Z[a]+1:1; N[a]=null; } } function zapEH(N) { var a,i,C; for (j in H) R(N,"on"+H[j]); C=N.childNodes; for (i=0;i<C.length;++i) zapEH(C[i]); } zapEH(document); for (j in Z) s += j + " (" + Z[j] + ")\n"; if(s) alert("Zapped event handlers:\n\n"+s); else alert("No event handlers found.");})();`  In the 'H' array, you can also include "cut","copy","contextmenu","mousedown" to remove the corresponding "on" events as well.

Comment: FWIW Apple now does `return false` for oncopy and oncut only... Reason prevailed?

Comment: @Triynko: why so complicated? It seems that something as simple already does the trick: `javascript: (function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var i=inputs.length;
    while(i--)
            inputs[i].setAttribute('onpaste', '');
})();`

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the consensus here: Denying copy and paste means that my really complex passwords (stored in 1Password) are useless.  So my response is to use short easily remembered passwords (i.e. weak ones).  Driving people to use weak passwords is a BAD idea.

Also, the onpaste="return false;" is part of the DOM, not a javascript add-on, I believe.  So it is really up to the site designer to stop such bad practices.

Does anyone know if there is a good reason to use "return false;" -- that is, is there something dangerous about the clipboard?  If so, it kind of invalidates the use of such programs as 1Password.

Comment: Some users use "password vaults" applications allowing auto-type or pasting the username and password to the login form.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with everyone, and the sad thing is the large companies are starting to adopt this practice now, I cant paste on paypal, xbox live, and also some apps such as roundcube block it by default.  I argue that its worse for security as it forces the enduser to type it meaning it either has to be an easy one to remember or they have to have it visible somewhere to type out, the good apps like keeppass work on the basis passwords arent visible but only copied to clipboard temporarily.

Answer (score 5):

Preventing copy/paste passwords is a TERRIBLE idea - it pretty much makes using long, randomly generated secure passwords impossible. Imagine I wanted to use "JFPEWm!QjVIdrFk8l|/%" as a password - it's a great password, but a nightmare to type and VERY error prone.

Answer (score 4):

**Non at all**

The user can disable anything thats client side, including your JScripts.  Your collegue is mis-informed, show them this thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is only improvement if you accept the premise that the source from which the password was copied is less secure than memorization...I think that's probably true. But it's coming at a pretty hefty price on usability. And most browsers have one capability or another to store passwords, and users use password managers, etc. I think at some point you just have to accept the limits of the username / password paradigm.

It might be useful to take a look at client certificate authentication, if you are really concerned about security. It's important to note that there's nothing **inherently more secure** about cca, it's just a different set of credentials. But it is, presumably more difficult to copy a cert than a password. In any case, it's a good thing to know about for your security toolbox:

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Client-Certificate-Authentication-IIS6.html
http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html

Comment: But the user needs to make that initial copy anyway before he realizes that the paste doesn't work. So that initial loading into clipboard will still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely to help. Keyloggers will now be sure to catch passwords. Copying and pasting the password is likely *more* secure than typing it.

Better to invest in a good password management tool and training (like Lastpass or 1Password) than frustrate users, making them more likely to take shortcuts (like using the same, simple password everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the consensus here.  I don't see how removing copy-and-paste functionality could improve security, and all JavaScript can be disabled anyway.  It's not worth your time.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys,

your answers are really supporting my position here.
I also fail to see the security benefit gained by removing the copy & paste capabilities from the webform.

However, it's a large scale web application, dealing with a lot of money, so it's hard to argue against anything that could possibly improve security (From a political point of view).

Greetings
Simon

Comment: But it doesn't improve security, it decreases it!

Comment: Just as @jammycakes says, it decreases security, that's my reason for the -1.